# 3 cards conditional probability problem

Tags: probability

> Suppose 3 cards are there - RR, RB, BB where R stands for red face and B stands for blue face. Let 1 card is drawn at random. One face is exposed and it is red. What is probability that other face is Blue?

On the face of it i thought if exposed face is red, we need P(other face Blue given that exposed face is red) = {other face B}/{ required sameple events are RR, RB} = 1/2

But text book answer is 1/3

He goes as follows:-
P(other face Blue given that exposed face is red) = P(R and other face B)/P(R)

```
        = P(RB picked up and exposed face is R) / P(R) 

        = (1/3*1/2)/(1/2) = 1/3
```

But where i went wrong. Kindly point me ....

Comment: Your error is in assuming that it is equally likely that the face that we saw originated from the `RR` card as from the `RB` card.  This is not the case.

This question is functionally equivalent to the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boy_or_Girl_paradox

Comment: to clarify JMoravitz's comment: there are 3 red faces, and only one of them has a blue face on the other side so 1/3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it helps to organize your thoughts, let each of the faces on each of the cards be uniquely labeled.  So, on the first card we have sides $R_1,R_2$.  On the second card we have $R_3,B_1$.  On the final card we have $B_2,B_3$.

You can recognize that each of the six individual faces are equally likely to have been shown.  Since we are told that there was a red face shown, that means that it was either $R_1,R_2$ or $R_3$ that was shown.  Had it been either of the first two, the opposite face would also be red while only the third has the opposite face as blue.

To reiterate my comment above, your error was in incorrectly assuming that of the possible outcomes in our conditioned sample space, that both were equally likely to occur.  That is not the case here, and probability being calculated as $Pr(A)=\dfrac{|A|}{|S|}$ is not correct in the event that the outcomes in our sample space are not equally likely to occur.

Comment: Sir i understood that RR and RB events are not equally likely. But how did u infer that? can you elaborate. I understood that if 1st  face is red, it has to be R1, R3. It can not be R2. I was earlier thinking that there are 2 events red and blue. So probability of red as 1st face = 1/2. But by just seeing Qn, how to infer that it is equally likely or not. I  am not good in probability. Please elaborate a bit

Comment: Is the Qn like given coin tossed 2 times. Given that 1st toss is head, what is probability of 2nd toss is tail. So possible outcomes out of sample space of 4 = H(H or T) = 1/2 ???

Comment: When we are shown a face, it wasn't specified that we are looking only at the top face.  Had we been explicitly told that we were shown one of the faces $R_1,R_3,B_2$, then your answer of $\frac{1}{2}$ would have been correct.  We were told "Let 1 card be drawn at random (*equally likely from all available cards*). One face (*chosen randomly equally likely from the faces available on that card*) is exposed"

Comment: There are three different ways in which we were shown a red face.  We could have picked the $R_1R_2$ card and then been shown $R_1$, we could have picked the $R_1R_2$ card and then been shown $R_2$ (*something that your original line of logic left out as a possibility*), or we could have picked the $R_3B_1$ card and been shown $R_3$.  This is precisely what led to the calculation given in the stated answer in your original post that led to a final answer of $\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: Undertood now that P(exposed face is R1 or R2 or R3) = 1/3. P((exposed face is R1 or R2 or R3) AND (other face is blue)) = ?   = P(exposed face R1 and other face blue) + P(exposed face R2 and other face blue) + prob(exposed face R3 and other face blue) = (0 + 0 + 1/3); P(exposed face R1, or R2 or R3) = 1/3; Now P(other face is blue given that exposed face is R1 or R2 or R3) = 1??? Again i am making mistake.

Comment: When exposed face is R3, other face is defenetely blue right. Intutively P(other face blue given that exposed face is R3) = 1? while P(other face is blue given that exposed face is R1 or R2) = 0.

Comment: Sir kindly reply with patience. I am asking so many questions. I want to improve.

Comment: I think here in this problem P(face is red) = 1/2; P(exposed face is red) = 1/3 Am i correct?

Comment: Exposed face is $R_1,R_2$ or $R_3$ will be $\frac{1}{2}$, not $\frac{1}{3}$.  Exposed face is $R_3$ and other face is blue is in fact $\frac{1}{6}$, not $\frac{1}{3}$.  Note that $Pr(R_3~\text{is shown}) = Pr(R_3B_2~\text{was the shown card})\times Pr(R_3 \text{was shown}\mid R_3B_2 \text{was the shown card})=\frac{1}{3}\times\frac{1}{2}$.  Similar calculations for the others

Comment: thank you sir. Got it now.

Answer (score 1):

All three red faces are equally likely to be shown.  Only one of them is on the RB card.

$$\mathsf P(\textsf{card is }RB\mid \textsf{face seen is }R)=1/3$$

---

By Bayes' Rule.   Obviously to see a face we must pick its card and flip up that face.

$${\mathsf P(\textsf{card is RR}\cap \textsf{face seen is R})=\tfrac 13\times\tfrac 11\\[2ex]\mathsf P(\textsf{card is RB}\cap \textsf{face seen is R})=\tfrac 13\times\tfrac 12\\\mathsf P(\textsf{card is RR}\mid \textsf{face seen is R})~{=\dfrac{\mathsf P(\textsf{card is RB}\cap \textsf{face seen is R})}{\mathsf P(\textsf{card is RR}\cap \textsf{face seen is R})+\mathsf P(\textsf{card is RB}\cap \textsf{face seen is R})}\\[3ex]=\dfrac{\tfrac 16}{\tfrac 13+\tfrac 16}\\[4ex]=\dfrac 13}}$$